# How to pass params to modify filters in Tableau to download PDF

Tags: powershell, api, tableau-api

I tried to download pdf from Tableau via its API using Powershell

with the following code:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $server/api/$api_ver/sites/$siteID/workbooks/$idineed/pdf?Split%20By=Region -Headers $headers -Method GET -OutFile "C:\test.pdf"
```

my intention  is to be able to filter my Tableau dashboard by passing parameters after ?. but It doesn't seems to work. PDF can be downloaded by not filtered.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are already running some kind of filter: `?Split%20By=Region`. Just remove it to get a clean PDF.

Comment: Try changing `\pdf` to `\view.pdf`